# How to pass operators as arguments in function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, arguments, operators

I want to pass logical operators in function as argument.

For e.g.

```
func openViewIfNeeded() {
    if lastTab != 0 {
      openView()
    } 
}
```

So , instead of `!=` operator directly , i want it as argument.

Function should be like as below:

```
func openViewIfNeeded(operator) {
   if lastTab (operator) 0 {
      openView()
   }
}
```

and this function should be call like this

```
self.openViewIfNeeded(!=) or self.openViewIfNeeded(==)
```

Any help is appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to provide the operator as a closure/function to `openViewIfNeeded`. See this example:

```
typealias Operator = (Int, Int) -> Bool

func compare (_ op:Operator) {
  if op(1,2) {
    print ("yes")
  }
}

compare(<)
```

Nevertheless, in the function you cannot write the operator as a literal; instead, you have to "call" the closure.